# Not able to browse the mdns service created in esp8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, mdns, dns-sd

**What I done till now is**

I created mdns service in my nodemcu

```
    ... // code used to create the mdns service 

    if (mdns.begin("esp", WiFi.localIP()))
        Serial.println("MDNS responder started");

    server.begin();
    Serial.println("HTTP REST Server Started");

    MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80); 

   ...
```

> Then I installed Bonjour in my windows . After that I am able to 
>   `ping esp.local` from my windows power shell and also I could
>   communicate with the iot device from browser using the mdns name
>   `esp.local` .

**The Issue Iam struggling with right now .**

Iam not able discover this device while searching for mdns services .
I used `dns-sd` in windows powershell to browse my service , but its not discovering this device .

the command is `dns-sd.exe -B <Type> <Domain> (Browse for services instances)`
 So I tried with

`dns-sd -B _http._tcp local.    //have doubt about this one .`

and its just showing

`Browsing for _http._tcp.local.`

**It would be great if any one could help me with this. Thanks.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `MDNS.addService("http", "tcp", 80);` to `mdns.addService("http", "tcp", 80);`

Solved the problem . `mdns` is my `MDNSResponder` object instance .

Answer (score 9):

for me, need to call `MDNS.update()` inside loop function to make it work.

Comment: I don´t see this documented, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

abhayastudios asked me to help you out.

Did you include ESP8266mDNS.h in your code?

You could always try to discover all your mdns devices using the android app called fing.
Did you check the windows services to see if bonjour printing service is running (or installed)? Sometimes windows stops this service.

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Thanks you for your response , it was a typo issue .

Answer (score 1):

These are the commands I use on MacOS which work for my friend's ESP8266 based device:

Browse HTTP Bonjour service instances:

```
$ dns-sd -B _http._tcp .
```

Resolve Bonjour service instance:

```
$ dns-sd -L <device name> _http._tcp .
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , I got it after fixing the typo issue .